# How to write CSS styles in a CSS files using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a CSS file **custom_style.css** and a HTML file **custom_render.html**.

**custom_render.html** contains some input field to take input from user and than generates **CSS styles** based on those input.

Now I want to store those **generated CSS styles** in a CSS file called **custom_style.css** [that is located in my projects root directory], so that I can show the users a preview/output of their selections.

After googling I got a way to store those generated CSS in the same file [**custom_render.html**] using JavaScript, but I want to store them in **custom_style.css**.

Can anyone tell me how can I write CSS Styles in CSS files using JavaScript or other JavaScript framework.
- Thanks

Comment: In web-based JS (i.e. not NodeJS), you can't directly write to files. That would be a huge security issue if browsers let webpages modify the filesystem. You _could_, however, prompt the user to download & save a custom-generated CSS file.

Comment: @siam PHP can't write to the user's files either, unless the OP is running a local PHP server.

Comment: @qxz I assumed OP tries to save the newly generated style in a `css` file that is located in OP's server. (as OP said *that is located in my projects root directory*) basically OP tries to override an existing css file (tho its a terrible idea)

Comment: @siam:: Currently I am not interested to do this task using PHP or something else.

Comment: @Shimul do you wanna save the styles for future reference or just to show the users their current changes?

Comment: @siam: Just to show the current changes. I or Users will not require those for future reference. Suppose you want to use a class **.target_class** in your HTML. If it is not stored in anywhere than how can you show the effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can modify the parameters of objects in your stylesheets.  For example:

```
document.styleSheets[i].rules[j].style.marginTop = "100px";
```

`i` being the number corresponding to the sheet you want to edit

and

`j` being which element rule you want to change the parameter for.

In this case I used `marginTop` as a paramater and `100px` as a value but it could be whatever valid CSS you would like.

Comment: How can I add class? Because all styles are rendered as class based. i.e:
.xyz {
 .....
......
}

.xyz + .abc {
 ......
 .....
}
and so on....

Comment: There's probably a better way than this, but off the top of my head I'd create 'template' class as the first item of your css that just has some benign attribute like `position: inherit` (or something like that).  Then you could do something like this:

    `var templateClass = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0];
    var numberOfRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules.length;
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[numberOfRules] = templateClass;
    document.styleSheets[0].rules[numberOfRules].style.marginTop = "10px";`

Sorry, I'm a stackOverflow n00b so don't know how to format this, haha.

Comment: OOPS, and I forgot to add you'll probably have to set the new class name like this:
`document.styleSheets[0].rules[numberOfRules].selectorText = ".myNewClass";`

Again, this is all just off the top of my head, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

simple... (assuming this is what you trying to achieve)

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('target_class');
// should use for loop to assign click event to each element containing this class
elem[0].onclick = function() {
  elem[0].style.background = 'green';
  elem[0].style.opacity = '0.2';
}
```

```html
<div class="target_class" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

insertRule(rule, index)
This will inserts a new rule to the stylesheet, where the parameter "rule" is a string containing the entire rule to add (ie: #myid{color: red; border: 1px solid black}), and "index", an integer specifying the position within cssRules[] to insert the new rule.

```js
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("p{font-size: 20px;}", 0) //add new rule to start of stylesheet
```